# Test for image in Codeception acceptance test

Tags: image, codeception

I'm setting up a load of automated testing for our in house CMS.

At this moment in time, I want to be able to test that our test page has certain images in it.

I can check for the caption which will be displayed if the image exists...

```
$I->see('Image Caption');
```

...but I really want to actually be able to check for the presence of the image itself...

```
$I->seeImage('/path_to/image_file.jpg'); // I MADE THAT METHOD UP
```

...or at least the img tag...

```
$I->seeSourceCode('<img src="/path_to/image_file.jpg"'); // I MADE THAT METHOD UP TOO
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the image "caption"? That is what I'm trying to do..

Comment: It was just a bit of text that I was using to check that the image had probably loaded, because I couldn't work out how to check the actual image had loaded. I think the solution below worked for me at the time, but to be honest, we're not using Codeception any more so I have probably forgotten everything about it by now!

Comment: In WordPress, images have "captions" which are just text meta data blurbs. They can be found just with $I->"see"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

seeElement() may fit your need, for instance:
`$I->seeElement('//img[@src="/pixel.jpg"]');`
please do [see doc](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#seeElement) 

 and, in order to make test more readable, I'd recommend to wrap the actual call to seeElement() in [helper](http://codeception.com/docs/03-ModulesAndHelpers#Helpers) and in test have something like this
`$I->seeImageWithSource('/pixel.jpg')`

```php
public function seeImageWithSource($image_url)
{
    $phpBrowser = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser');
    $phpBrowser->seeElement('//img[@src="'.$image_url.'"]');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This one works out of the box...

`$this->seeElement('//img[@src="'.$image_url.'"]');`

But I agree about wrapping it, so I add this in WebHelper

    `public function seeImageWithSource($image_url)
    {
        $this->seeElement('//img[@src="'.$image_url.'"]');
    }`

Ran the build command and tried...

`$I->seeImageWithSource($image_url);`

but got Call to undefined method Codeception\Module\WebHelper::seeElement().

What amd I doing wrong?

Comment: You should invoke `seeElement` method from PhpBrowser module instance, i.e.
    `public function seeImageWithSource($image_url)
    {
        $phpBrowser = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser');
        $phpBrowser->seeElement('//img[@src="'.$image_url.'"]');
    }`